# VS 2012 All Toolbox items are greyed out

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Just installed VS 2012 Express and started a new MVC internet website and it seems that all my toolbox items are greyed out and unable to use them.  its as if the IDE thinks that I am trying to use them in a code-behind file.  But my active window is Index.cshtml and I cant seem to access any toolbox items.

I am new to VS 2012 and I know I am just doing something silly.

Comment: Found answer.  at this link:
[Stack-Overflow answer to why you cant use webform toolbox items in MVC Apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894473/does-asp-net-mvc-use-the-regular-toolbox-controls)

Comment: Found answer. at this link:
[Stack Overflow Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894473/does-asp-net-mvc-use-the-regular-toolbox-controls)